# String in struct

Tags: c++, string, struct

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;

struct node
{
    std::string a;
};

int main()
{
    cout << str << endl;
    struct node* p = (struct node*)(malloc(sizeof(struct node)));
    p->a = "a";
    cout << p->a;
    return 0;
}
```

The above code produces a runtime error. The struct is working for ints but when I try to use string as its member variable, error occurs. It also gives runtime error on codechef ide.

Comment: First of all, please try to indent your code better to make it readable; second, try to explain exactly what kind of error it gives.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

C++ is not C.

You shouldn't `#include` anything from the `bits` folder.

You should not use `malloc` to allocate memory. You should use `new` instead:

```
node* p = new node();
```

Or just don't dynamically allocate memory at all:

```
node p;
```

C++ is not C.

Answer (score 4):

Don't use `malloc`: the constructor for `std::string` will **not** be called and so the object created will be in an undefined state.

Use `new` instead. The C++ runtime will then call the default constructor for the `std::string` member. Don't forget to match the `new` with a `delete`.

Answer (score 4):

You forget to declare `str`. Also, don't use `new` (and *certainly* not malloc!!!) unless you have to (read: never):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;
struct node {
    std::string a;
};
int main()

{
    std::string str;

    cout << str << endl;

    node p;
    p.a = "a";
    cout << p.a;
}
```